# Have elements sequentially change with delay in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to have a row of dots sequentially change with a small delay (between each dot changing) but am having trouble. This is what I have so far:

```
const Dots = () => {
  const [currentDot, setCurrentSegment] = useState(1);

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <StyledLargeDot
        onClick={() => setCurrentSegment(1)}
        isActive={currentDot >= 1}
      />
      <StyledLargeDot
        onClick={() => setCurrentSegment(2)}
        isActive={currentDot >= 2}
      />
      <StyledLargeDot
        onClick={() => setCurrentSegment(3)}
        isActive={currentDot >= 3}
      />
      <StyledLargeDot
        onClick={() => setCurrentSegment(4)}
        isActive={currentDot >= 4}
      />
      <StyledLargeDot
        onClick={() => setCurrentSegment(5)}
        isActive={currentDot >= 5}
      />
      <StyledLargeDot
        onClick={() => setCurrentSegment(6)}
        isActive={currentDot >= 6}
      />
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

export default Dots;

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  background: green;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 100vw;
`;

const StyledLargeDot = styled.div`
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  height: 5px;
  opacity: ${(props) => (props.isActive ? "1" : "0.3")};
  transform: ${(props) => (props.isActive ? "scale(2)" : "")};
  transition: all 0.5s 1s linear;
  width: 5px;

  &:hover {
    transform: ${(props) => (props.isActive ? "" : "scale(2)")};
    opacity: ${(props) => (props.isActive ? "" : "1")};
  }
`;
```

A "working" example is here : https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-smoke-qlv2i?file=/src/components/Dots.js

What I want to happen is:

The first dot (left to right) to always be active. WORKING

When another dot is clicked then the dots between it activate sequentially with a small delay until the clicked dot lights up last. NOT WORKING - The clicked dot activates first and the ones in between don't activate sequentially.

If a previous dot it clicked then the dots after it to deactivate sequentially (from right to left) until they get to it but it remains active. NOT WORKING - The clicked one remains active but the ones in between seem to deactivate together not sequentially.

Ideally, any unactivated dots will scale to activated size on hover without activating. NOT WORKING but I know why and could probably figure it out after fixing everything else.

As you can see, what I have done kind of works but not really. I think I can figure out the hover but the real issue is the sequence and timing which I m stumped on :/

I am not even sure if this is even the best approach to this and really would appreciate some help please?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-ramanujan-h41iu TADA!

First I created an array with an object to hold the properties of each dot

```
const initialDots = [
  { isActive: true, delay: 0},
  { isActive: false, delay: 0},
  { isActive: false, delay: 0 },
  { isActive: false, delay: 0 },
  { isActive: false, delay: 0},
  { isActive: false, delay: 0 }
];
```

The I mapped the each element to a `<StyledLargeDot {...dot} onClick={() => handleChange(index)} />.` The handle change function will mutate the array to get the proper effect.

```
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      {dots.map((dot, index) => {
        return (
          <StyledLargeDot {...dot} onClick={() => handleChange(index)}/>
        );
      })}
    </Wrapper>
  );
```

I later changed this to what is bellow to add the Hover functionality because the transition delay of the `<StyledLargeDot/>` made it difficult to add any hover effect without a delay.

```
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      {dots.map((dot, index) => {
        return (
          <div
            onClick={() => handleChange(index)}
            style={{ position: "relative" }}
          >
            <StyledLargeDot {...dot} />
            <HoverEffect {...dot} />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </Wrapper>
  );
```

I had to make the changes below to your  component to take in the new `delay` property.

```
const StyledLargeDot = styled.div`
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  height: 5px;
  opacity: ${(props) => (props.isActive ? "1" : "0.3")};
  transform: ${(props) => (props.isActive ? "scale(2)" : "")};
  transition: all 0.5s ${(props) => props.delay}s linear;
  width: 5px;
`;
```

The important part is the `handleChange()` function which makes the effect possible. It works after a dot is clicked by calculating the proper transition delay of each dot, and updating properly the `isActive` property. The `delayFix` variable isn't neccesary but you can set it to 0 to see the diffrence.

```
  const [dots, setDots] = useState(initialDots);
  const handleChange = (currentIndex) => {
    let delayFix = currentIndex > currentDot ? -1 : 0;
    setDots(
      dots.map((dot, index) => {
        return {
          isActive: index <= currentIndex,
          delay: Math.abs(index - currentDot) + delayFix
        };
      })
    );
    setCurrentSegment(currentIndex);
  };
```

To get the `<HoverEffect/>` working I created this component below.

```
const HoverEffect = styled.div`
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  opacity: 0.3;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  :hover {
    opacity: ${(props) => (props.isActive ? "0.3" : "1")};
    transform: ${(props) => (props.isActive ? "" : "scale(2)")};
  }
`;
```